# SELECT single column of ipv6 FROM guest OR user, whichever is NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null, mariadb

I can easily do the following:

```
SELECT INET6_NTOA(users.ipv6) AS ipv6_user, INET6_NTOA(guests.ipv6) AS ipv6_visitor
```

However is there a way to have a *single column* returned with whichever column is not null?

I would not do this often though the opportunity to learn something new just presented itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to have a single column returned with whichever column is not null?

You seem to be looking for `coalesce()`:

```
COALESCE(INET6_NTOA(users.ipv6), INET6_NTOA(guests.ipv6)) AS ipv_visitor
```

`coalesce()` returns its first non-`null` argument (or `null` if both are `null`).

Comment: "You can accept this answer in 12 minutes." - a preemptive thank you.